# Print / Explode PHP string with slashes

Tags: php, string, split, hex, explode

I have the following IP address encoded as a string:

```
"\x7F\0\0\x01"
```

While I can figure with my eyes how it is encoded (octet, slash, octet ... ), I can't manipulate in PHP.

I've tried to split (explode) with \ (or double ) as its separator, but no luck.

```
>>> $d['_ip']
=> "\x7F\0\0\x01"
>>> $ip = explode("\\", $d['_ip'])
=> [
    "\x7F\0\0\x01",
    ]
```

When I try to echo, it doesn't print.

```
>>> echo $d['_ip']
⏎
>>>
```

I need to get each octet as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're sending, I presume, is from Javascript or JSON.  The literal characters '\', 'x', '7', etc. are not what's being sent.  What that string represents are four individual bytes, each from 0 - 255.

Try this:

```
$ip = str_split($d['_ip']);   // Break the string into an array of individual bytes
$ip = array_map('ord', $ip);  // Map those bytes to their integer equivalents via the `ord()` function
$ip = implode('.', $ip);      // Cast the bytes back to strings and connect with dots
```